# Can I change the rate at which matplotlib updates the 'motion_notify_event' event?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a program where I can interact with the plot by dragging control points. If the plot window is small, then the plot updates smoothly when the control points move. However, when the plot window is large, the plot does not updates smoothly (it lags and skips around) when the control points are moved.  Here I recreate the problem with one of the simplest matplotlib examples with the `motion_notify_event` mouse event.

I believe the `motion_notify_event` mouse event is updated based on the pixels the mouse traverses because if I increase the window size the update is slower, as in it lags because the program is having to update too frequently. Is it possible to tell the mouse event to update only every other pixel or less often in some way?

```py
# Draggable rectangle with blitting.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class DraggableRectangle:
    lock = None  # only one can be animated at a time

    def __init__(self, rect):
        self.rect = rect
        self.press = None
        self.background = None

    def connect(self):
        """Connect to all the events we need."""
        self.cidpress = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_press_event', self.on_press)
        self.cidrelease = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'button_release_event', self.on_release)
        self.cidmotion = self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_connect(
            'motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)

    def on_press(self, event):
        """Check whether mouse is over us; if so, store some data."""
        if (event.inaxes != self.rect.axes
                or DraggableRectangle.lock is not None):
            return
        contains, attrd = self.rect.contains(event)
        if not contains:
            return
        print('event contains', self.rect.xy)
        self.press = self.rect.xy, (event.xdata, event.ydata)
        DraggableRectangle.lock = self

        # draw everything but the selected rectangle and store the pixel buffer
        canvas = self.rect.figure.canvas
        axes = self.rect.axes
        self.rect.set_animated(True)
        canvas.draw()
        self.background = canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.rect.axes.bbox)

        # now redraw just the rectangle
        axes.draw_artist(self.rect)

        # and blit just the redrawn area
        canvas.blit(axes.bbox)

    def on_motion(self, event):
        """Move the rectangle if the mouse is over us."""
        if (event.inaxes != self.rect.axes
                or DraggableRectangle.lock is not self):
            return
        (x0, y0), (xpress, ypress) = self.press
        dx = event.xdata - xpress
        dy = event.ydata - ypress
        self.rect.set_x(x0+dx)
        self.rect.set_y(y0+dy)

        canvas = self.rect.figure.canvas
        axes = self.rect.axes
        # restore the background region
        canvas.restore_region(self.background)

        # redraw just the current rectangle
        axes.draw_artist(self.rect)

        # blit just the redrawn area
        canvas.blit(axes.bbox)

    def on_release(self, event):
        """Clear button press information."""
        if DraggableRectangle.lock is not self:
            return

        self.press = None
        DraggableRectangle.lock = None

        # turn off the rect animation property and reset the background
        self.rect.set_animated(False)
        self.background = None

        # redraw the full figure
        self.rect.figure.canvas.draw()

    def disconnect(self):
        """Disconnect all callbacks."""
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidpress)
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidrelease)
        self.rect.figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cidmotion)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects = ax.bar(range(10), 20*np.random.rand(10))
drs = []
for rect in rects:
    dr = DraggableRectangle(rect)
    dr.connect()
    drs.append(dr)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can currently think of is adding a variable that keeps track of how many times the connected function has been called. I'll call this `n_motion_events`. Then after some number `on_motion` calls the function body is executed and counter is reset.

```py
# Draggable rectangle with blitting.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class DraggableRectangle:
    lock = None  # only one can be animated at a time

    def __init__(self, rect):
        self.rect = rect
        self.press = None
        self.background = None
        self.n_motion_events = 0
        self.skipEveryNEvents = 5

    """
    ...
    """

    def on_motion(self, event):
        self.n_motion_events += 1
        if n.motion_events >= self.skipEveryNEvents:
            self.n_motion_events = 0
            """Move the rectangle if the mouse is over us."""
            if (event.inaxes != self.rect.axes
                    or DraggableRectangle.lock is not self):
                return
            (x0, y0), (xpress, ypress) = self.press
            dx = event.xdata - xpress
            dy = event.ydata - ypress
            self.rect.set_x(x0+dx)
            self.rect.set_y(y0+dy)

            canvas = self.rect.figure.canvas
            axes = self.rect.axes
            # restore the background region
            canvas.restore_region(self.background)

            # redraw just the current rectangle
            axes.draw_artist(self.rect)

            # blit just the redrawn area
            canvas.blit(axes.bbox)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects = ax.bar(range(10), 20*np.random.rand(10))
drs = []
for rect in rects:
    dr = DraggableRectangle(rect)
    dr.connect()
    drs.append(dr)

plt.show()
```